# center ul inside my div

Tags: html, css, html-lists, center

I would like to center my ul container inside my div.

So my div has got a width of 100% and margin set to auto.

For the ul It has a width of 98% and a margin set to auto

```
width: 98%;
margin: auto;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

The trouble I'm having is that the li are not centered inside so the menu is aligned to the left. I would like to display it in the center position

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Below is the url of my website http://www.barbarian-strongman28.fr/

Comment: I've tried but it does not work

Comment: Ok, then can you post a complete code example and a jsFiddle?

Comment: which part of the code do you want ? my website is accesible there http://www.barbarian-strongman28.fr/

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want you dont even need margin auto, just text align if you also put 100% with to your list items. If you can make a sketch of what you want it's easier to help you.

Comment: It is accessible but we can't modify it. So jsFiddle would be better. Part of the code that is relevant to this question

Comment: ok, I will try it because I do not know how it work, give me few seconds please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ul.art-hmenu have float, remove it (float:none) and `text-align:center` in `.desktop-nav .art-nav-inner` (and either need the 98% width)

This make the whole ul behave like a single word (cause it's display: inline-block).... and align to the center (as text).

Answer (score 1):

The relevant HTML is the following:

```
<div class="art-nav-inner">
  <ul class="art-hmenu">
    <li> <a href="accueil.html" class="active"> accueil</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="calendrier-et-resultats.html" class="active"> 
           calendrier et résultats</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="multimedia.html" class="active"> multimedia</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="athletes.html" class="active"> athlètes</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="partenaires.html" class="active"> partenaires</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="contact.html" class="active"> contact</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="media-presse.html" class="active"> médias et presse</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

To center the navigation links, add/modify the following CSS rules:

```
ul.art-hmenu
{
    text-align: center;
}

ul.art-hmenu li
{
    display: inline-block; /* float: left; no need to float the items */
}
```

When displayed as inline-blocks, the `li` elements can be centered within the parent
element using `text-align: center`.